# Effect of Insertion order on number of collisions in Double Hashing

Tags: hash-tables

How is the number of collisions affected by the order of insertion of elements in a hash table using double hashing?

I've tried uing different hash function for double hashing with different set of values. The position of the elements in the hash table seem to change but the number of collsion remains the same so far.

Comment: It's unclear what, exactly, you're asking.  If your. hash functions are good, meaning the location where any element ends up is seemingly random, then it doesn't really matter what hash function you use.  If you use a bad hash function you're going to get bad results.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but in real-life situations I am not sure that you can choose the insertion order.